# Impossible to insert Membership type column in a View for Display Contacts

Tags: civimember, contact-view, column

I will try to be as schematic as possible:

- I have a specific group (our Member Organizations);
- We have 4 different types of membership (Full, Associate, Specialist, Applicant);
- I want to display these types of membership in the list of contacts of the group.

I tried to:
- create a profile with Membership types and status, but CiVi gives me back the following errors:

[image]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
[image]

Before you ask, I managed to change the default views from here: /civicrm/admin/setting/search?reset=1, so my only question is:

HOW CAN I DISPLAY THE MEMBERSHIP TYPES AND STATUS AS A RESULT COLUMN FOR PROFILE SEARCHES?

Thanks to everyone who will help me.